# how to count the number of nested in tuples and how to union this list of tuples

Tags: haskell

1.how to count the number of nested in tuples

2.got error when union, even if number of nested are the same, how to union this list of tuples?

error:

```
<interactive>:13:1:
    No instance for (Eq Expr) arising from a use of `union'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq Expr)
    In the expression: union b1 b2
    In an equation for `it': it = union b1 b2
```

haskell code:

```
countnest :: (Int,Int) -> Int
countnest ((a1,a2), (b1,b2)) = max (max ((countnest (fst (a1,a2)))+1) ((countnest (snd (a1,a2)))+1)) (max ((countnest (fst (b1,b2)))+1) ((countnest (snd (b1,b2)))+1))
countnest (a1, (b1,b2)) = max 0 (max ((countnest (fst (b1,b2)))+1) ((countnest (snd (b1,b2)))+1))
countnest ((a1,a2), b1) = max (max ((countnest (fst (a1,a2)))+1) ((countnest (snd (a1,a2)))+1)) 0
countnest (a1, a2) = 1
countnest a1 = 1

rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate _ [] = []
rotate n xs = zipWith const (drop n (cycle xs)) xs

rev2 :: [a] -> [a]
rev2 (x:[]) = [x]
rev2 (x:xs) = rev xs ++ [x]

flatten1 :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten1 xss = foldr (++) [] xss

getUniqueOrder :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
getUniqueOrder xs = nub ( map sort xs)

getUnique :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
getUnique xs = nub (xs)

data Expr = A | B | C | D | S | M2 | M1 | MM1 deriving (Show)
let cartProd xs ys = [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
let m1 = cartProd [A,S] [B,M2]
let m2 = (cartProd (cartProd (cartProd [A,S] [B,M2]) [C,M1]) [D])  
let m3 = m2 ++ [(((S,MM1),MM1),MM1)]

let a1 = m3
let b1 = [rotate y a1 | y <- [0..(length a1 -1)]]
let a2 = rev a1
let b2 = [rotate y a2 | y <- [0..(length a2 -1)]]
union b1 b2
```

when compile countnest got error, after tried many times, still can not 
find where is wrong, already match pattern

```
*Main> :l oo.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( oo.hs, interpreted )

oo.hs:140:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
                with actual type `((Int, Int), (Int, Int))'
    In the pattern: (a1, a2)
    In the pattern: ((a1, a2), (b1, b2))
    In an equation for `countnest':
        countnest ((a1, a2), (b1, b2))
          = max
              (max
                 ((countnest (fst (a1, a2))) + 1) ((countnest (snd (a1, a2))) + 1))
              (max
                 ((countnest (fst (b1, b2))) + 1) ((countnest (snd (b1, b2))) + 1))

oo.hs:140:21:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
                with actual type `((Int, Int), (Int, Int))'
    In the pattern: (b1, b2)
    In the pattern: ((a1, a2), (b1, b2))
    In an equation for `countnest':
        countnest ((a1, a2), (b1, b2))
          = max
              (max
                 ((countnest (fst (a1, a2))) + 1) ((countnest (snd (a1, a2))) + 1))
              (max
                 ((countnest (fst (b1, b2))) + 1) ((countnest (snd (b1, b2))) + 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
countnest :: (Int,Int) -> Int
countnest ((a1,a2), (b1,b2)) = ...
```

Function definition here is inconsistent with declaration. But it is not just a mistake: the thing you calling "tuple" is actually a tree, so you probably need a code like this instead:

```
data NestType = ConsLeaf Int | ConsPair NestType NestType

countnest :: NestType -> Int
countnest (ConsLeaf _) = 1
countnest (ConsPair x y) = max (countnest x) (countnest y) +1
```

Comment: if define custom type, it is not tuple any more. is it possible to count tuple directly? moreover, how to union b1 and b2 in above case? how to use this custom type?

Comment: countnest (ConsPair (ConsPair (ConsLeaf 1) (ConsLeaf 2)) (ConsLeaf 3)) i know how to use now

Comment: Do you mean "union" is concatenate? ((1,2),3) -> [1,2,3] ?

Comment: got some difficulty when change to this data Expr = A | B | C | D | S | M2 | M1 | MM1 deriving (Show)
data NestType = ConsLeaf Expr | ConsPair NestType NestType
let cartProd xs ys = [(ConsPair (ConsLeaf x),(ConsLeaf y)) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
let m2 = (cartProd (cartProd (cartProd [(ConsLeaf A), (ConsLeaf S)] [(ConsLeaf B),(ConsLeaf M2)]) [(ConsLeaf C),(ConsLeaf M1)]) [(ConsLeaf D)])

Comment: union is concatenate [((1,2),3)]  [((4,5),6)] to [((1,2),3), ((4,5),6)]

Comment: then it is just ConsPair.

Comment: And if you want tuples exactly, try
    data NestType = ConsLeaf Int | ConsPair (NestType, NestType)